# cargo run: can't find crate even though it's listed in Cargo.toml

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am using a Rust script called `build.rs` for code generation (it's not a Cargo build script). The script contains this at the top:

```rust
extern crate reqwest;
```

This is my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "my-script"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[[bin]]
path = "build.rs"
name = "builder"

[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.10", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
```

When I do `cargo run`, it gives me this error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `reqwest`
 --> build.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate reqwest;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

How do I make it able to find the `reqwest` crate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`build.rs` is the default name for a [Cargo build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html), which is ran at build time to generate code, link in C libraries, etc.

Since cargo sees that you have a `build.rs` in your project directory, it assumes its a build script and tries to build it. However build scripts don't use the normal dependencies and instead use dependencies from the `[build-dependencies]` section of `Cargo.toml`. Since you don't have one, the `reqwest` crate isn't available to the build script.

Renaming the file is an obvious fix. However the convention is to put executables into the `bin/` directory of your project (cargo will even automatically find files in there for you).

Answer (score 0):

The `build.rs` script needs a different name. Rename `build.rs` to `builder.rs` and update `Cargo.toml`:

```
path = "builder.rs"
```

You can also remove `extern crate reqwest` statement because it's inferred by Cargo.